# If $G$ is connected then $\lambda_2 < \lambda_1$.

Tags: graph-theory, spectral-graph-theory

Let $G=(V,E)$ be an $n$-vertex , undirected graph with maximum degree $d$, then how to prove
the following result.

If $G$ is connected then $\lambda_2 < \lambda_1$. where $\lambda_1 \geq \lambda_2 \geq \cdots \geq \lambda_n$ are eigen values of adjacency matrix of G.

Can someone help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A basic question in Spectral Graph Theory. Please refer to Dr. Spielman's notes. [(link is here)](http://www.cs.yale.edu/homes/spielman/561/lect03-12.pdf)